# How to append values to new columns based on computation of other columns in python?

Tags: python, dataframe, if-statement

I want to check if the `date1` column is less than the other `date2` column, then create a new column or `New Column` and assign 1, 0 otherwise. If the calculation is `NaT` then save `NaT` to the newly created column. Here is my trial.

```
if df['date1'] < df['date2'] == True:
    df['New Column'] = '1'
elif df['date1'] < df['date2'] == 'NaT':
    df['New Column'] = 'NaT'
else:
    df['New Column'] = '0'
```

But this does not seem to work and throwing `ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().` I am still learning Python and any help on this would be really appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When asking questions please provide reproducible data like the following so those answering your questions don't have to create it.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'date1':['2000-03-01', '2000-03-02'], 
    'date2':['2000-04-01', '2000-02-02'],
})
print(df)
        date1       date2
0  2000-03-01  2000-04-01
1  2000-03-02  2000-02-02
```

First create your column setting the value to zero.

```
df['New Column'] = '0'
```

Then filter and set values:

```
df.loc[df['date1'] < df['date2'], 'New Column'] = '1'
print(df)
        date1       date2 New Column
0  2000-03-01  2000-04-01          1
1  2000-03-02  2000-02-02          0
```

I'm not sure what you are trying to do with 'NaT' in this context. Perhaps applying isnat?